# How to animate & control Android PreferenceFragment screens?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-preferences

I have a `PreferenceFragment` whose contents are defined in XML. These contents include a child `PreferenceScreen`. When I click on the `PreferenceScreen`, the new screen is rendered successfully, but it has no animation (it just shows up on screen, even before the Material ripple is finished on Lollipop devices).

Even worse, if I had any complex layout going on (for example, the `PreferenceFragment` was in a tab on one side of the screen) that layout is blown away and replaced with a full-screen fragment.

I suspect that if I find the callback or event that occurs when a `PreferenceScreen` is clicked, I can solve both problems, but I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I did this for a slide in right-to-left animation of the PreferenceFragment...
I extended the PreferenceFragment and overridden the `onCreateView()` like this:

```
 @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    AnimRelativeLayout animRelativeLayout = new AnimRelativeLayout(getActivity());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    animRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    animRelativeLayout.addView(view);
    return animRelativeLayout;
}
```

where `AnimRelativeLayout.java` is

```
public class AnimRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

private IMovementListener mMovementListener;

public AnimRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.initMembers();
}

public AnimRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.initMembers();
}

public AnimRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.initMembers();
}

private void initMembers() {
    this.mMovementListener = new SimpleMovementListener();
}

public float getXFraction() {
    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    return (width == 0) ? 0 : getX() / (float) width;
}

public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    this.mMovementListener.onSetXFraction(xFraction);
    setX((width > 0) ? (xFraction * width) : 0);
}

public float getYFraction() {
    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int height = size.y;
    return (height == 0) ? 0 : getY() / (float) height;
}

public void setYFraction(float yFraction) {
    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int height = size.y;
    this.mMovementListener.onSetYFraction(yFraction);
    setY((height > 0) ? (yFraction * height) : 0);
}

public interface IMovementListener {
    public void onSetXFraction(float pXFraction);

    public void onSetYFraction(float pYFraction);
}

private class SimpleMovementListener implements IMovementListener {

    @Override
    public void onSetXFraction(float pXFraction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSetYFraction(float pYFraction) {

    }
}
```

and then did this:

```
pFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(
                    R.animator.slide_in_right_to_left, R.animator.slide_out_right_to_left,
                    R.animator.slide_in_left_to_right, R.animator.slide_out_left_to_right
            )
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .commit();
```

and an example for `R.animator.slide_in_right_to_left` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="300"
        android:propertyName="xFraction"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```